# Auto require lib files in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to extend the String class in my Rails 4.2 app.  I created a **lib/string.rb** file to hold the extensions.

```
class String
  def testing
    "testing"
  end
end
```

I added `lib` to autoload_paths in application.rb.

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

When I startup the rails console and execute `"".testing`, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'testing' for "":String`

**Can anyone explain why this method isn't getting picked up?**  I have a hunch that it's because the `String` constant is already loaded, so Rails doesn't need to autoload the constant.  As a result, it never tries to load the `lib/string.rb` file and my method never gets added to String.

When I explicitly require the file in an initializer, I can get the method loaded, but if I change the method, I have to restart the server to get rails to see the change.  It feels like I'm missing something.  It seems like there should be a way to get Rails to automatically read core extension classes and reload them when the file changes.

Comment: I put all of my monkey patches in lib/monkey and add the following to the bottom of application.rb: Dir.glob(Rails.root.join 'lib', 'monkey', '**', '*.rb').each {|f| require f}

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up creating an initializer with `Dir.glob(Rails.root.join 'lib', 'autorequire', '**', '*.rb').each {|f| require f}`.  This will find all .rb files inside the `lib/autorequire` directory and all sub directories no matter how deeply nested they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you're right. It will not autoload string since it's already defined. I usually put core class extensions inside an initializer. So config/initializers/string.rb

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.  I try and keep the initializers focused on configuration and avoid putting functionality in the initializers.  It definitely works, but it seems cleaner to let the code live in lib, and require it from an initializer or application.rb.